# Como obtener el nombre del país del cliente - Android

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, geolocalización

Necesito poder almacenar correctamente el **nombre real** del pais del cliente donde se utiliza la app, actualmente lo hago de esta forma:

```
PaisRegistro = Java.Util.Locale.Default.ToString();
```

Pero esto me da un resultado asi:

```
en_US
```

Lo que yo traduzco de esta forma:

```
Idioma: Ingles
Pais: US (Estados Unidos de Norte America).
```

Pero necesito poder obtenerlo de esta forma:

```
PaisRegistro: Colombia / Estados Unidos //--(Ejemplos)
```

Comment: podrías tener diccionarios/Lista con todas las keys de idioma y país, y de ahí buscar en ellos por el nombre como los necesitas. anexo un listado de ello: http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/207-Get-All-Language-Country-Code-List-for-all-Culture-in-C---ASP-Net.aspx

Comment: Es una idea muy interesante y relativamente simple, gracias por mencionarla. Creo que la usare pero la otra razon por la que buscaba un metodo alterno es tambien porque en ocasiones hago pruebas de Login desde mi pais y me pone: es_US y yo no estoy en EEUU.

Comment: desconozco el porqué, pero mera suposición, supongo que si no puede obtener la ubicación ha de poner esa por default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Locale* no te da la información del país, te da la información del IDIOMA que está configurado. *en_US* no significa "una persona que habla inglés en Estados Unidos", significa "una persona que habla inglés, con la variedad de Estados Unidos" (y puede haber subvariedades).

Si me llevo mi móvil a Estados Unidos, el *locale* seguira siendo *es_ES*.

Para saber donde está una persona, hay varias opciones:

- Preguntar al usuario.
- Usar algún servicio de geolocalización por IP. No es 100% efectivo, pero puede servir para una primera aproximación (y si el usuario quiere cambiar, le das la opción).
- Usar la ubicación del móvil. Hay una clase *Geocoder* que, a partir de la ubicación, te da la información del país. El inconveniente es que tu aplicación necesita permisos para acceder a la ubicación, y el usuario se puede negar a dárselos.

Hay una cuarta opción que es acceder a la información de la tarjeta SIM, pero solo te dice de que país es la tarjeta (si mueves el móvil de país no lo registra) y también necesita permisos.

Comment: Muy detallado. Te agradezco.